# Need some input on a jQuery carousel

Tags: jquery

I'm making a jquery carousel and i got the left/right scroll working as supposed.

But i also need a list navigation with schortcuts to each slide, and i don't get it working as i like.

My thought was to use index() to find a elements positon and then scroll to element by width * position, but it does not work. It returns different values each click.

Also i'm i need to find some smart solution to which direction it should scroll.

And as a bonus, does anyone have a elegant solution to prevent the user to speedclick many times in a row? It does scroll continuously then. And if there is only 3 slides, a blank appears. Tried with stop() with no luck :/

My code is here

http://jsfiddle.net/n8mEV/1/

Any helt much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to prevent spam click.
Ex :

```
var inAnimation = false;
$('.thumbnail-carousel-nav li').click(function(){
    if (inAnimation) return false;
    inAnimation = true;
/* More code */
 $(current_carousel).animate({'left' : left_indent},500,function(){    
            inAnimation = false;
/* ... */
```

To prevent blank pages in scrolls back/next, you must make a copy of the first and last item and respectively append and prepend them to your list like :

```
<li>4th Item</li>

<li>1st Item</li>
<li>2nd Item</li>
<li>3rd Item</li>
<li>4th Item</li>

<li>1st Item</li>
```

This is the code for only one picture shown.

Comment: Thank you, alreadt moved items like that, but it does not help if theres few items and the user clicks to fast. Will try your inAnimation thingie.